# Failed to execute goal com.oracle.servicebus.plugin

Tags: oracle, maven, osb

I'm trying to package an OSB 12 application, consisting of more projects with maven 3, with the servicebus plugin.
I'm getting this error:

Failed to execute goal com.oracle.servicebus.plugin:oracle-servicebus-plugin:12.1.3-0-0:package (default-package) on SomeProject: Creation of the Service Bus Configuration Archive failed. See the log in the build directory for more information.

But there is no more information in the log, nor does the -e or -X switches give me more about this which are supposed to give me a more verbose output. I know that plugin errors are like this but this servicebus plugin does not seem to be well documented, is there any way I could pinpoint the exact cause?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a very late answer but, as I found your question while having the same issue, it might still help someone today.

I believe that the log file this refers to is the one in `.data\maven\configjar\configjar.log` within the OSB project.

But that did not help me much when I had the issue. All that was in there was: `The system cannot find the path specified.` It turns out that my effective POM was having the wrong value for `<oracleHome>` property. Once I set this one correctly in my user settings, it all worked fine.

And the reason I had the wrong value in the first place was that my environment variable for `ORACLE_HOME` was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer provided by Akro but issue still persisted for me. I found something else which worked for me so adding the fix here.

Error in cmd/shell for the `mvn package` command:

```
Failed to execute goal com.oracle.servicebus.plugin:oracle-servicebus-plugin:12.1.3-0-0:package (default-package) on SomeProject: Creation of the Service Bus Configuration Archive failed. See the log in the build directory for more information.
```

Log file `.data\maven\configjar\configjar.log` contains the error: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Before doing the maven plugin installation for OSB 12.1.3, I changed a file as below. Please use the jdk path to your jdk installation instead of the one provided in my sample:

File: `ORACLE_HOME\osb\tools\configjar\setenv.bat`

Change: Add a line `set JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_351` at the beginning of the file setenv.bat.

After this do your maven plugin setup normally.
This resolved my issue.

Original reference I found for a different version of setup with the same error which gave me the hint.: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/osb-with-jenkins-and-maven-12-2-1-2-0-cannot-find-the-path-7561#comment_323462169894116847738854745227496434537